# Struct does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'

Tags: swift

I wish to create an array which will only hold unique instances of a struct:

```
  var vowelSet: Set<NotificationStruct>
```

Here is my struct:

```
struct NotificationStruct{
    let dateHeader: String
    let sensorName: String
    let message: String
    let time: String
}
```

yet I keep getting the error: "does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'"
here is what I tried:

```
 struct NotificationStruct<T: Hashable>{
```

Comment: `struct NotificationStruct: Hashable`, implement the required methods, or wait for Swift 4.1 to have them implemented by compiler :)

Comment: You are asking for an array, but you are creating a Set...

Comment: well, I can settle for an Set

Comment: Gah! I hate when I waste time on an answer only to have the question deleted or closed out from under me before I can post it ... If you need a `Set` of unique values, see here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable

Answer (score 0):

In the original question you are saying an array but creating a Set. Do you need something like this:

```
struct NotificationStruct {
    let sensorName :String
    let message :String
}

var vowelsArray = [NotificationStruct]()
```

Comment: You should ask for a clarification in a comment. This "answer" really isn't an answer.

Comment: but i dont want any duplicates in array... I can setting for Set

Comment: When you are adding to the array then at that point you can check for duplicates. @rmaddy You can be a little nicer :)

Comment: @azamsharp Sorry, in what way wasn't I being nice? I simply posted a suggestion. Please don't read intent that isn't there.

Comment: ok that link above provided with the solution fixed my Struct, but how do I make an instance of it?  this didnt work:     let xd = Set<NotificationStruct1> = Set

Comment: `var xd = Set<NotificationStruct>()`